# Let the user change language with a select

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I need to let the user change language with a select. I need to do everything by hand because i'm putting that in a custom block. Do you have any idea on how I can accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what i did in the end:

php

```
$path = drupal_is_front_page() ? '<front>' : $_GET['q'];
$type = 'language_url';
global $language ;
$lang_name = $language->language ;
$links = language_negotiation_get_switch_links($type, $path);
$languages =array();
$htmlSelect = "<select id='selezioneLingua'>";
foreach ($links->links as $id => $link) {
    $prefix = $link['language']->prefix;
    $selected = '';
    if ($lang_name == $prefix){
        fb('same');
        $selected = 'selected';
    }
    $htmlSelect .= "<option $selected value='$prefix'>$link[title]</option>";
    $href = ($link['href'] === '<front>') ? '' : '/'.$link['href'];
    $languages[$link['language']->prefix] = "?q=".$link['language']->prefix.$href;
}
$htmlSelect .= "</select>";
drupal_add_js(array ("languagepages" => $languages), 'setting')
```

javascript:

```
jQuery('#selezioneLingua').change(function(){
    var val = jQuery(this).val();
    var languages = Drupal.settings.languagepages;
    window.location.href = languages[val];
});
```

Comment: This was helpful as I'd missed out the prefix from the URL. Thanks for solving my problem!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the language switcher simply has

```
?language=[2letter-language-code]
```

appended to the end of each page's URL.

for instance, switching to Portuguese language for node 4 is:

```
<a href="/node/4?language=pt" class="language-link">Portuguese, International</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also a module for this [Language Switcher Dropdown](http://drupal.org/project/lang_dropdown). Here is a quote about it (from its project page):

> ... exposes a new block, similar to the default Language Switcher block provided by Locale module.
>
> The new block allows site visitors to switch languages using a drop-down select list instead of using hyperlinks.
>
> The module also integrates well with [Language Icons](http://drupal.org/project/languageicons) module if installed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Nicola Peluchetti's answer, but slightly different:

```
global $language ;
$path       = drupal_is_front_page() ? '<front>' : $_GET['q'];
$currlang   = $language->language ;
$links  = language_negotiation_get_switch_links('language_url', $path);
$content    = "<select id='iaf-language-select'>";
foreach ($links->links as $id => $link) {
    $selected = ($currlang == $id)?'selected':'';
    $href = url($link['href'],array(
        'absolute'  => true,
        'language'  => $link['language']
    ));
    $content .= "<option $selected value='$href'>$link[title]</option>";
}
$content .= "</select>";
```

.. add a `onchange="document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex.value)"` to your likings